# How to get data from component

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js.

*list.vue:*

```
<template>
  <div class="m-products-list">
    <ul @mouseover="over">
      <Item
        v-for="(item,idx) in parentList"
        location="item.location"
        :key="idx"
        :meta="item"/>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    over: function (e) {
      let dom = e.target;
      let tag = dom.tagName.toLowerCase();
      if (tag === 'dd') {
        console.log(dom.getAttribute('location'))
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The `Item` is from its parent component. And I want to get `item.location` in `over()` when I mouseover an `item`, but `console.log` always returns `null`. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried to check dom.attributes to see if it get other attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically possible (but there may be a better alternative shown in the next section) by setting a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-*) in the `Item`.

```
// Item.vue
<li :data-location="location" class="item" ... >
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {id: 1, location: 'New York'},
        {id: 2, location: 'Los Angeles'},
        {id: 3, location: 'Chicago'},
      ]
    }
  },
  components: {
    Item: {
      props: ['location'],
      template: `<li :data-location="location" class="item">{{location}}</li>`,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    over(e) {
      console.log(e.target.dataset.location)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.7/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul @mouseover="over">
    <Item v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.id"
          :location="item.location" />
  </ul>
</div>
```

A better solution that doesn't require DOM manipulation would be to use the data model in Vue and to move the `mouseover` event listener to the `Item`:

1. Change the argument of `over()` to the location name (previously the event object):

   ```
   methods: {
     over(location) {
       /* ... */
     }
   }
   ```
2. Move the `@mouseover` event-listener annotation from `ul` to the `Item` in the template, and pass the `item.location` as an argument:

   ```
   <ul>
     <Item v-for="item in items" @mouseover="over(item.location)" ... />
   </ul>
   ```
3. Edit the `Item`'s template to forward its `mouseover` event to the parent:

   ```
   // Item.vue
   <li @mouseover="$emit('mouseover', $event)" ... >
   ```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {id: 1, location: 'New York'},
        {id: 2, location: 'Los Angeles'},
        {id: 3, location: 'Chicago'},
      ]
    }
  },
  components: {
    Item: {
      props: ['location'],
      template: `<li @mouseover="$emit('mouseover', $event)" class="item">{{location}}</li>`,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    over(location) {
      console.log(location)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.7/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <Item v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.id"
          :location="item.location"
          @mouseover="over(item.location)" />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Harry No problem :)